# Suppose $X \leq M$ holds true. If $M$ is a random variable and $P(M \leq c)=p,$ can we say that $P(X \leq c) \geq p?$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X \leq M$ holds true.  Now, if $M$ is a random variable and $P(M \leq c)=p,$ can we say that $P(X \leq c) \geq p?$ Any clarifications\hints\suggestions?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb P(c\lt X \le M)+\mathbb P(X \le c \le M)+\mathbb P(X\le M \lt c)=\mathbb P( X \le M)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega$ such as $M(\omega) \leq c$ then  $X(\omega) \leq M(\omega) \leq c$

Therefore
$\{M \leq c\} \subset \{X \leq c\}$